# how to get file content in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, file

I used to get file content using JQuery this way:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get('/data.json', function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

now I need to do it just using javascript, would you please help me :)

Comment: To me, the given snippet looks like Javascript - what are you searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fetch api.

```html
<script>
   fetch('/data.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    request.open("GET", "/data.json", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == "200") {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
```

Comment: why not use the new fetch API?